# Error code 1236 from GetQueuedCompletionStatus function

Tags: windows, sockets, c++11, networking

I get error code 1236 from GetQueuedCompletionStatus() function, I tried to debug with vs but still cant figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you may need anymore information.
I create new thread whenever create room request sent to server.
This is my workerThread:

```
unsigned __stdcall serverWorkerThread(void* completionPortID) {
    HANDLE completionPort = (HANDLE)completionPortID;
    DWORD transferredBytes, flag = 0;
    LPPER_HANDLE_DATA perHandleData;
    LPPER_IO_DATA perIoData;
    LPUSER user;
    while (1) {
        if (GetQueuedCompletionStatus(completionPort, &transferredBytes, (PULONG_PTR)&perHandleData, (LPOVERLAPPED*)&perIoData, INFINITE) == 0) {
            if (GetLastError() != 64) {
                printf("Error %d: GetQueuedCompletionStatus() failed\n", GetLastError());
            }
            else {
                user = (LPUSER)perIoData;
                disconnect(user);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        user = (LPUSER)perIoData;
        if (transferredBytes == 0) {
            disconnect(user);
            continue;
        }
        if (perIoData->operation == RECEIVE) {
            perIoData->recvBytes += transferredBytes;
        }
        else {
            perIoData->sendBytes -= transferredBytes;
            strcpy_s(perIoData->sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE, perIoData->sendBuff + transferredBytes);
        }
        int len;
        if (perIoData->sendBytes > 0) {
            sendMess(user);
        }
        else if ((len = checkEndMessage(perIoData->recvBuff, perIoData->recvBytes)) != -1) {
            string message(perIoData->recvBuff, perIoData->recvBuff + len - 2);
            string result = handleRequest(user, message);
            perIoData->recvBytes -= len;
            strcpy_s(perIoData->recvBuff, BUFF_SIZE, perIoData->recvBuff + len);
            strcpy_s(perIoData->sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE, result.c_str());
            strcat_s(perIoData->sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE, DELIMITER);
            perIoData->sendBytes = result.size() + 2;
            sendMess(user);
        }
        else {
            recvMess(user);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my room thread:

```
unsigned __stdcall examThread(void* ptrRoom) {
    LPROOM room = (LPROOM)ptrRoom;
    string question = "EXAM " + room->exam->question;
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point startTime;
    getTime(room->startTime, startTime);
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(startTime);
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    room->status = ON_GOING;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    for (USER* user : room->contestant) {
        strcpy_s(user->perIoData.sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE, "STARTTEST ");
        strcat_s(user->perIoData.sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE, question.c_str());
        strcat_s(user->perIoData.sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE, "\r\n");
        sendMess(user);
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::minutes(room->duration));
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    room->status = FINISH;
    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(1));
    EnterCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    listRoom.erase(std::find(listRoom.begin(), listRoom.end(), room));
    LeaveCriticalSection(&criticalSection);
    delete room;
    return 0;
}
```

After sendMess(user), I return error code 1236 from GetQueuedCompletionStatus.
This is my struct:

```
typedef struct PER_IO_DATA {
    WSAOVERLAPPED overlapped;
    WSABUF wBuff;
    char recvBuff[BUFF_SIZE];
    char sendBuff[BUFF_SIZE];
    int operation;
    int recvBytes;
    int sendBytes;
    PER_IO_DATA() {
        ZeroMemory(&overlapped, sizeof(WSAOVERLAPPED));
        ZeroMemory(recvBuff, BUFF_SIZE);
        ZeroMemory(sendBuff, BUFF_SIZE);
        sendBytes = 0;
        recvBytes = 0;
    }
} *LPPER_IO_DATA;

typedef struct USER {
    PER_IO_DATA perIoData;
    PER_HANDLE_DATA perHandleData;
    string name;
    int status;
    LPROOM inRoom;
    USER() {
        status = CONNECTED;
    }
} *LPUSER;
```

sendMess function:

```
void sendMess(LPUSER user) {
    LPPER_HANDLE_DATA perHanleData = &(user->perHandleData);
    LPPER_IO_DATA perIoData = &(user->perIoData);
    DWORD transferredBytes, flag = 0;
    perIoData->operation = SEND;
    perIoData->wBuff.buf = perIoData->sendBuff;
    perIoData->wBuff.len = perIoData->sendBytes;
    if (WSASend(perHanleData->socket, &(perIoData->wBuff), 1, &transferredBytes, flag, &(perIoData->overlapped), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        if (WSAGetLastError() != WSA_IO_PENDING) {
            printf("Error %d: WSASend() 1 failed", WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't show your GetQueuedCompletionStatus() code, but error 1236 is ERROR_CONNECTION_ABORTED, which means you are losing your socket connection. But, I do see that you are not assigning a proper value to `perIoData->sendBytes`, so the IO could simply be failing. But, it looks like you are freeing your room data before GetQueuedCompletionStatus() is called, how does that affect your IO? Can you provide a better [mcve]? Also, your use of InitializeCriticalSection() and DeleteCriticalSection() is wrong, too.

Comment: When GetQueuedCompletionStatus() returns FALSE, if the returned OVERLAPPED* is NULL then GetQueuedCompletionStatus() itself failed and GetLastError() tells why, otherwise the IO operation failed and GetLastError() tells why. But you are not differentiating between those two conditions. Also, examThread() is still not setting perIoData->sendBytes to the size of the data in perIoData->sendBuff before calling sendMess(). And what does ROOM look like? Does destroying a ROOM destroy the data buffer you are sending? DONT destroy the data buffer before the IO finishes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have fixed this problem, it appeared because I forgot set ' perIoData->sendBytes ', thank you very much. And I destroy ROOM 1 hour after I send mess to user so I think I doesnt affect

Comment: "*I destroy ROOM 1 hour after I send mess to user*" - that is very dangerous logic. And besides, why would you want to make that thread hang around for an hour doing absolutely nothing? What if the user wants to exit your app during that time? You should destroy the room when you are actually done using it, ie in serverWorkerThread() when there is no more data to exchange.

Comment: error code 1236 NOT from GetQueuedCompletionStatus(), but from I/O operation. from WSASend or WSARecv, etc. you need know this by check operation.